# How to get a dynamic IP adress Kubuntu

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, dynamic-ip

I don't understand how can I get dynamic IP, so it will change sometimes. How can I do it?

Some outputs that shall help:

```
    :~$ ifconfig -a
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.1.44  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6d9:f5ff:fe61:993d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:d9:f5:61:99:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6401  bytes 4589258 (4.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6549  bytes 777805 (777.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ham0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1404
        inet 25.73.193.214  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 25.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::7879:19ff:fe49:c1d6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7a:79:19:49:c1:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 56  bytes 6478 (6.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 573  bytes 73295 (73.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 573  bytes 73295 (73.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and this file that I setup by a tutorial to get dynamic IP:

```
~: cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

Comment: DHCP gives you dynamic ip-address.

Comment: and what does it mean?

Comment: I can use this: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-setup-a-dhcp-server-with-ubuntu-server-18-04/?

Comment: What are you trying to achive ? You computer is setup yo get ip-address from your internet provider. For DSL connections thats normally your "modem" but it can also be a server somewhere by the ISP.

Comment: I want so my Ip adress will change and be not static so anybody can get where my provider is

Comment: Nobody on the internet can see your ip-address. The provided address (10.0.1.44) is a private none-routeable address. To be able to access your system from the internet you will need a static public address - thats a service you have to pay your ISP extra for.

Comment: I mean my public IP (which is static) for example on websites always locate to where my provider city is (near me).

Comment: so I have to contact my provider?

Comment: So I care not about people who can get access to my PC. I do care about my location. I thought it would be better to have dynamic IP which will change sometimes, so people can't detect where I am.

Comment: It does not work that way. If you want to change your location use VPN or Proxy.

Comment: Ok. So, anyway if I wanna get dynamic IP only my ISP can help me in this case?

Comment: Yes, sometimes if you reboot your router your ISP might choose to change your IP address, but the address they give is entirely up to them. You can use a service called a VPN (eg Mullvad) that hides your IP address; the services IP address, roughly speaking, makes the requests for you and then forwards them to your IP address. Depending on the VPN and the law where you are they can keep the information about who used which IP address so that they can give it to the police later; even services that say they won't do this have been found to do it.